# Two different Integration results for the same integrand in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I want to calculate
$$
\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta\, \left(\sqrt{1 \over 1-\left(1-(1-\gamma^2)^4\right)\cos^2\theta} - 1\right)^q
$$.

For the simplest case of $q=1$ we have

```
q = 1;
A1 = Assuming[gamma ∈ Reals && 0 <= gamma < 1,
   Integrate[Sin[theta] (Sqrt[1/(1 - (1 - (1 - gamma^2)^4) Cos[theta]^2)] - 1) , theta]
   ];

B1 = Limit[A1, theta -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow"]  - Limit[A1, theta -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"];
B1 /. gamma -> 0.1
```

gives

```
0.0133732 + 0. I
```

Now, let's define $a = \left(1-(1-\gamma^2)^4\right)$, put it in the integrand and after integration put the value of $a$ back to the final expression in terms of $gamma$:

```
q = 1;
A2 = Assuming[a ∈ Reals && 0 <= a < 1,
   Integrate[Sin[theta] (Sqrt[1/(1 - a Cos[theta]^2)] - 1), theta]
   ] /. a-> (1 - (1 - gamma^2)^4);

B2 = Limit[A2, theta -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow"]  - Limit[A2, theta -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
B2 /. gamma -> 0.1
```

which gives

```
-31.6393 + 0. I
```

The two results are totally different symbolically and numerically, while the integrand is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A1` and `A2` have expressions containing logarithms meaning you run the risk of 'over-integrating' around the non-principal values of the logarithm - remember that $\log(z) = \log(|z|)+i (\arg(z)+2k\pi)$. If you add some additional assumptions `theta >= 0 && theta \[Element] Reals` to your `A2` you get a matching answer with zero imaginary part:

```
A2 = Assuming[
    a \[Element] Reals && 0 <= a < 1 && theta >= 0 && 
     theta \[Element] Reals, 
    Integrate[Sin[theta] (Sqrt[1/(1 - a Cos[theta]^2)] - 1), 
     theta]] /. a -> (1 - (1 - gamma^2)^4);

B2 = Limit[A2, theta -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow"] - 
  Limit[A2, theta -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
B2 /. gamma -> 0.1
(*0.0133732*)
```

Comment: Amazing! loved it!! Thanks a lot! Do you have a reference to suggest to me to read on this issue? I have no background to understand "'over-integrating' around the non-principal values of the logarithm" and I am interested to learn. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm. Are you familiar with complex numbers? Basically $e^{i k}$ goes round and around a unit circle in the complex plane. This means if you take the inverse (the logarithm) there's the usual answer in the real numbers called the principal value, but also many more complex answers.

Comment: Try this to get a feel for it: `Manipulate[ListPlot[
  {{Re[Exp[I \[Pi] k]], Im[Exp[I \[Pi] k]]}},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.25, 1.25}, {-1.25, 1.25}}, AspectRatio -> 1],
 {k, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`